# wpf Datagrid :Position Listview when Datagridcell textchange

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I want to position a Listview when the Datagridcell text change .My datagrid has a column namely Product, when the user type something on that column a small listview popup with Products hence the user can select one product from the listview and the product is displayed on the datagrid's Product column .My problem is that I can't position the Listview near the cell which I edit.

My XAML is :

```
<!--My datagrid-->
<my:DataGrid Name="dgvSales" BeginningEdit="dgvSales_BeginningEdit" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="13,150,9,117" KeyDown="dgvSales_KeyDown" MouseDown="dgvSales_MouseDown" PreparingCellForEdit="dgvSales_PreparingCellForEdit" >
                    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="naam" Header="Code" Width="120" Binding="{Binding ProductCode}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name" Width="200" Binding="{Binding ProductName}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Unit" Width="100"></my:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Purchase Rate" Width="100" Binding="{Binding PurchaseRate}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Qty}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Amount}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
                    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
                </my:DataGrid>

<!--My listview-->
<ListView Height="161" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lstvwProductCode" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Width="388">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Record_Id}" Header="Record ID" Width="0" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Code}" Header="Pcode" Width="110" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Name}" Header="Product" Width="180" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you put your Listview in RowDetailsTemplate of your DataGrid and set the bindings accordingly to populate the listview.

```
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView Height="161" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lstvwProductCode" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Width="388">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Record_Id}" Header="Record ID" Width="0" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Code}" Header="Pcode" Width="110" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Name}" Header="Product" Width="180" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Comment: when the user select an item from the listview the item is shown on the Product Name column of my datagrid and the listview must be invisible how to do this...?

Comment: When an item is selected from the listview ,the item must be shown on the first column 'Product Name' of the datagrid and also product code to the 'product code' column of the datagrid how to acheive this sir ?

Comment: i will need to see your UI and model code buddy to help you..can you share that